# EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined on EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sqlgeography

I've checked various posts about this, but my problem is not solved. I am using EF6, so my namespace is **System.Data.Spatial**, my reference is **System.Data.Entity** and still I get this error:

```
Geocoder.DbGeography: : EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key defined.
Define the key for this EntityType.
DbGeographies: EntityType: EntitySet 'DbGeographies' is based on type 'DbGeography' that has no keys defined.
```

My entity is like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Geo { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This means that EF treaded `DbGeography` as a plain-old C# class, not a spatial type. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/spatial) show you have to reference the `System.Data.Entity` assembly and use the `System.Data.Spatial` namespace

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am exactly doing this.